# Solving an ODE with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE ?

$$y'-xy=e^x\tag*{}$$

---

My approach :

Here, integrating factor,

$$\begin{align}\mu &=e^{\int (-x)\, \mathrm{d}x}\\ &=e^{-x^2/2}\end{align}\tag*{}$$

So, after multiplying by the integrating factor, the ODE becomes

$$\begin{align}ye^{-x^2/2} &= \displaystyle \int e^x e^{-x^2/2}\, \mathrm dx \end{align}\tag*{}$$

The last integral can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions I think. Is there any way to proceed from here ? If there is any mistake in my method, please point it out.

Comment: The solution you have found is explicit and unique. That's the function $y(x)$ that satisfies the ODE (plus constant) $$ye^{-x^2/2}=\int e^x e^{-x^2/2}\, \mathrm dx+C$$, why would you expect any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: what do you define as a non usual integral?

Secondly we can write the integral in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function):

$$\int\exp\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\space\text{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}}\cdot\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{C}\tag1$$

Comment: Yes. Error function is not an elementary function. And by usual integral, I meant an integral expressible in terms of elementary functions.  :)

Comment: @DarkKnight Maybe that are the words you have to write instead of 'non usual integral'. But this is the answer to your integral (and the solution to your DE).

Comment: Thank you. I shall edit. And thank you again for the answer.

Comment: @DarkKnight Nice, I'm glad that I could help and you're more than welcome.